# Red warning triangle in top bar

Tags: apt, ppa

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

This is the error output. What's reason for this and what is a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

The links you've attempted to connect to are broken or dead links, and so are no longer supported.

You can solve the issue by;

Installing `ppa-purge`: `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

...and removing the links:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next
```

Comment: Updating packages lists
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
PPA to be removed: kirillshkrogalev ffmpeg-next
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: kirillshkrogalev ffmpeg-next

Comment: @AdriansNetlis could you paste the contents of the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file in you question?

Comment: Did it! ##Filling with useless characters##